# Dynamic SQL executed inside a stored procedure in a TRY/CATCH block but the error is not returned

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, try-catch

I have a simple stored procedure shown below. As you can see, the error is forcefully generated inside the dynamic SQL and passed to the CATCH block. The problem is that the details I expect are not returned. All I get back is this message:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure myproc, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 2]

Why don't I get back the information as coded in the CATCH block - procedure name, error line and error message?

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1/0'
        EXEC sp_executesql @nSQL
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERROR_NUMBER INT;
        DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY INT;
        DECLARE @ERROR_STATE INT;
        DECLARE @ERROR_PROCEDURE NVARCHAR(128);
        DECLARE @ERROR_LINE INT;
        DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000);
  
        SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER();
        SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY();

        SELECT @ERROR_STATE = CASE 
                                 WHEN ERROR_STATE() = 0 THEN 1
                                 ELSE ERROR_STATE()
                              END;
        SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        SET @ERROR_LINE = ERROR_LINE();
        SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = 'ERROR in ' + @ERROR_PROCEDURE + '; (ERROR Line: ' + CAST(@ERROR_LINE AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '); ' + 'ERROR MESSAGE: '
                            + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ';';

        RAISERROR(@ERROR_MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, @ERROR_STATE);
        RETURN (1);
    END CATCH;
```

Comment: What is the point of the catch, only to reraise it again? And if you want to reraise, why not just `THROW;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["ERROR_PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> `ERROR_PROCEDURE` returns `NULL` if the error did not occur within a stored procedure or trigger.

Since the dynamic SQL is not a procedure nor a trigger, this applies here and your `@ERROR_PROCEDURE` is `NULL`.

Now you use `@ERROR_PROCEDURE` in a string concatenation using `+` and assign that to `@ERROR_MESSAGE`. If you lookup the remarks in ["+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you'll see that this can lead to the result of the concatenation being `NULL` and that likely happens in your case.

> When you work with strings with a null value, the result of the concatenation depends on the session settings. Just like arithmetic operations that are performed on null values, when a null value is added to a known value the result is typically an unknown value, a string concatenation operation that is performed with a null value should also produce a null result. However, you can change this behavior by changing the setting of `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` for the current session.

So you pass a `NULL` as the first argument for `RAISERROR` and therefore no message is printed.

You can use `concat()` instead of `+` for the concatenation or replace `NULL`s manually.

But you should avoid `RAISERROR` anyway. See the note in ["RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

> The `RAISERROR` statement does not honor `SET XACT_ABORT`. New applications should use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`.

Answer (score 1):

`ERROR_PROCEDURE()` is `NULL` because the error occurred in the inner scope of the dynamic SQL statement, not in the stored procedure itself. If you want the name of the current proc, use `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above version, it is recommended to use [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Changing your whole **CATCH** block to below should be enough:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW
END CATCH;
```

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

> Divide by zero error encountered.